# How to load a TMemoryStream from a UnicodeString

Tags: devexpress, c++builder-2010

I am trying to fill a DevExpress VCL `TdxRichEditControl` with the string of a calculated RTF file without taking the time to save the file.  So, here is a demo project:

```cpp
void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    UnicodeString txt = "{\\rtf1\\deff0{\\fonttbl{\\f0 Calibri;}{\\f1 Arial Unicode MS;}{\\f2 Britannic Bold;}}{\\colortbl ;\\red0\\green0\\blue255 ;\\red255\\green0\\blue0 ;}{\\*\\defchp \\fs22}{\\*\\defpap \\sl275\\slmult1\\sa200}{\\stylesheet {\\ql\\sl275\\slmult1\\sa200\\fs22 Normal;}{\\*\\cs1\\fs22 Default Paragraph Font;}{\\*\\cs2\\sbasedon1\\fs22 Line Number;}{\\*\\cs3\\ul\\fs22\\cf1 Hyperlink;}{\\*\\ts4\\tsrowd\\fs22\\ql\\sl275\\slmult1\\sa200\\tscellpaddfl3\\tscellpaddl108\\tscellpaddfb3\\tscellpaddfr3\\tscellpaddr108\\tscellpaddft3\\tsvertalt\\cltxlrtb Normal Table;}{\\*\\ts5\\tsrowd\\sbasedon4\\fs22\\ql\\sl275\\slmult1\\sa200\\trbrdrt\\brdrs\\brdrw10\\trbrdrl\\brdrs\\brdrw10\\trbrdrb\\brdrs\\brdrw10\\trbrdrr\\brdrs\\brdrw10\\trbrdrh\\brdrs\\brdrw10\\trbrdrv\\brdrs\\brdrw10\\tscellpaddfl3\\tscellpaddl108\\tscellpaddfr3\\tscellpaddr108\\tsvertalt\\cltxlrtb Table Simple 1;}}{\\*\\listoverridetable}\\nouicompat\\splytwnine\\htmautsp\\sectd\\pard\\plain\\ql\\sl275\\slmult1\\sa200{\\f1\\fs28\\cf1 This is in blue }{\\b\\i\\f2\\fs40\\cf2 Red bold}\\b\\i\\fs22\\cf2\\par}";
    TMemoryStream *AStream = new TMemoryStream();

    AStream->WriteBuffer(txt.c_str(), txt.Length());
    AStream->Position = 0;

    AStream->SaveToFile("C:/Trash/Test.rtf");
    AStream->Position = 0;

    dxRichEditControl1->Document->InsertDocumentContent(dxRichEditControl1->Document->Range->Start, AStream, TdxRichEditDocumentFormat::Rtf);
    AStream->Free();
}
```

I saved it to a file in this demo to see what is going wrong and found the file contains a space in every other character (so, of course, the component I was trying to fill with this data failed to display anything).  When I look at the file, this is the type of stuff I see:

```
{ \ r t f 1 \ d e f f 0 { \ f o n t t b l { \ f 0   C a l i b r i ; } { \ f 1   A r i a l   U n i c o d e   M S ; } { \ f 2   B r i t a n n i c   B o l d ; } } { \ c o l
```

I want to stick with storing txt variable as a `UnicodeString`, because the real project has a class that calculates that string, but any ideas how to fix this issue?  I realize I could probably do something time consuming like loop through and eliminate every other character, but I want some efficient solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RTF is a 7-bit ASCII format, so you should not be treating it as UTF-16 at all.  The correct solution is to simply change the `UnicodeString` to an `AnsiString`:

```cpp
AnsiString txt = ...;
```

The "extra spaces" are due to `0x00` bytes being added when the 7-bit ASCII characters are extended to 16-bit values in UTF-16.

Besides, you are not even writing the `UnicodeString` to the `TMemoryStream` correctly anyway. Since `WriteBuffer()` deals with raw bytes, not string characters, you would need to multiply `txt.Length()` by `sizeof(System::WideChar)` to get the correct byte count:

```cpp
UnicodeString txt = ...;
...
AStream->WriteBuffer(txt.c_str(), txt.Length() * sizeof(WideChar));
```

If you change to `AnsiString`, you don't need to multiply since `sizeof(AnsiChar)` is 1.

But, if you are set on sticking with `UnicodeString`, then at least use `TStringStream` instead, so that you can specify a byte encoding for it:

```cpp
UnicodeString txt = ...;
TStringStream *AStream = new TStringStream(txt, TEncoding::ASCII);
...
```

Also, since the stream is created with `new`, you should change `AStream->Free();` to `delete AStream;` instead.  NEVER call `TObject::Free()` *directly* in C++, that is a Delphi idiom.  The C++ way to free something that is allocated with `new` is `delete`. It will call the `TObject` destructor as expected, just as `TObject::Free()` does.

Comment: Thanks Remy.  Based on your answer, I found a simple answer.  I just added "AnsiString txtAnsi = UTF8Encode(txt);" and changed the other references of "txt" to "txtAnsi".  It may waste a little bit of time/space, but is a quick and dirty solution.

Comment: Assigning a UTF-8 string to an `AnsiString` will convert the UTF-8 data to ANSI, which is lossless only for ASCII characters. And it is just a wasted conversion in this situation. `UTF8Encode()` is deprecated since C++Builder 2009, when `UnicodeString` was introduced. If you really want to convert the `UnicodeString` to a UTF-8 string, just use `UTF8String` instead: `UTF8String txtUtf8 = txt;` But this is really unnecessary since `TStringStream` can encode the `UnicodeString` data to ASCII/ANSI/UTF8 without you having 2 copies of the ASCII/ANSI/UTF8 data in memory.

Comment: I had trouble with TStringStream. The constructor has a third boolean parameter which is optional in Delphi (defaults to true) and required in C++.  Putting either true or false in for the parameter both has the same result in my sample program - both fail.

Comment: @VicFanberg `TStringStream` is a `TMemoryStream` descendant in CB2009+. There is *virtually no difference* between creating a `TMemoryStream` directly and manually writing UTF-8 data into it, versus creating a `TStringStream` with a `UnicodeString` and `TEncoding:::UTF8`. The `TStringStream` constructor will simply convert the `UnicodeString` to a UTF-8 byte array and have the base `TMemoryStream` take ownership of it. You can easily verify that the two types of streams produce the same data. The 3rd constructor parameter is ignored for standard `TEncoding` encodings, like `TEncoding::UTF8`.